# Change the centralWidget's content

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt

I'm begginer with qt and I have many questions.

One of them is how can I change the centralWidget's content. I have my `main.py` which is a
`QMainWindow` and contains my "menu" of my software. When I click on the "Validation" button I want change the centralWidget to show something else like the following exemple :

[image: Application menu] [image: Application frame 2]

How would you keep just one `QMainWindow` and change every time I need the `centralWidget` ?

Comment: Setting a [`QStackedWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) as central widget of your `QMainWindow` may be appropriate in this case.

Comment: e.g. with a [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) as central widget